# rspec have_selector with div and i elements are not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have upgraded my capybara from 2.x to capybara 3.13.x noticed that

```
  expect(html).to have_selector("div", "result-item-area")
```

starts failing tried various fix but nothing helped me and unable to figure out the reason for the below failure

```
Unused parameters passed to Capybara::Queries::SelectorQuery : ["result-item-area"]
```

Comment: That call was never valid. Previous versions of Capybara just ignored the invalid argument being passed and the newer version raises an error.  What are you expecting the “result-item-area” argument to do because it wasn’t doing anything previously.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasWalpole

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check wheather `div` with class `result-item-area` exists, you should use following code:

```
expect(html).to have_selector('div', class: 'result-item-area')
```

Or

```
expect(html).to have_selector('div.result-item-area')
```

Alternatively for `id`:

```
expect(html).to have_selector('div', id: 'result-item-area')
```

Or

```
expect(html).to have_selector('div#result-item-area')
```